# Ionic 4 | Http in function gives undefined data

Tags: function, typescript, http, ionic-framework, subscribe

I'm trying to get data from MySQL server.

But I'm having a problem where I'm trying to fetch a return value from the function. It works when just changing the value of a variable.

```
text;

    ionViewDidLoad()
  {
      this.http.post("http://192.XXX.XXX.XXX/magento/query.php", JSON.stringify({
          sql: "SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar` WHERE entity_id = 1 AND attribute_id = 73"
      })).subscribe(outp => {
          this.text = JSON.stringify(outp);
      }, error => {
          return error;
      });
  }
```

However, when I put it in a function, it outputs "Undefined".

```
text;

    ionViewDidLoad()
  {
      this.text = JSON.stringify(this.query("SELECT * FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar WHERE entity_id = 1 AND attribute_id = 73"));
  }

query(sql: string)
  {
      this.http.post("http://192.XXX.XXX.XXX/magento/query.php", JSON.stringify({
          sql: sql
      })).subscribe(outp => {
          return outp;
      }, error => {
          return error;
      });
  }
```

Please help...

Comment: from where are you passing the sql data to query()?

Comment: when i set the text variable in `ionViewDidLoad();` after `JSON.stringify(`...